# How can we disable/hide the Add ,edit and delete icons in material table in react JS?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I have highlighted the buttons which needs to be disabled/hidden.

Comment: Where is the code that you have tried??

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the editable prop.

```
<MaterialTable
    editable={{
        isEditable: rowData => rowData.name === "a", // only name(a) rows would be editable
        isDeletable: rowData => rowData.name === "b", // only name(a) rows would be deletable
        onRowAdd: newData =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    {
                        /* const data = this.state.data;
                        data.push(newData);
                        this.setState({ data }, () => resolve()); */
                    }
                    resolve();
                }, 1000);
            }),
        onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    {
                        /* const data = this.state.data;
                        const index = data.indexOf(oldData);
                        data[index] = newData;                
                        this.setState({ data }, () => resolve()); */
                    }
                    resolve();
                }, 1000);
            }),
        onRowDelete: oldData =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    {
                        /* let data = this.state.data;
                        const index = data.indexOf(oldData);
                        data.splice(index, 1);
                        this.setState({ data }, () => resolve()); */
                    }
                    resolve();
                }, 1000);
            })
    }}
/>
```

would become just

```
<MaterialTable/>
```

You can find more information in the [official documentation](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable).

If that doesn't help, please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can check that document for more details.

Editable Example check this tab on that page

https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable

or this think help you

```
  components={{
        Action: 
            props => {
                    if(props.action.icon === 'edit'){
                        return(
                        <Button
                        onClick={(event) => props.action.onClick(event, props.data)}
                        color="primary"
                        variant="contained"
                        style={{textTransform: 'none'}}
                        size="small"
                        disabled
                        >
                        My Button 
                        </Button>
                        )
                    }
                    if(props.action.icon === 'save'){
                        return(
                            <Button
                            onClick={(event) => props.action.onClick(event, props.data)}
                            color="primary"
                            variant="contained"
                            style={{textTransform: 'none'}}
                            size="small"
                            >
                            My Button 
                            </Button>
                        )
                    }
                }

      }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the functionality from createTableActions.
For eg if you don't want delete and add but want edit.

```
    const createTableActions = (tableName: string, setData:React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<object[]>>) => {
  const { isEditable } = SP_LIST_CONFIG[tableName];

  return isEditable
    ? {
        onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve();
          }),
      }
    : {};
};
```